# How to create multiple multi-range sliders with respective text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying work on multirange sliders, Where each slider has its respective text box which shows the changed value dynamically.

The problem which am facing is if i change one slider the values will get changed in other text boxes also please refer the image attached. How do i bind slider and its respective text box so as to achieve result like, if i ondrag the slider the value should get changed only its respective text box and same with the other sliders

below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>colResizable &#8211; range slider demo</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />  
    <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"> 
    </script>
    <script  src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script  src="../../colResizable-1.6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){   

    //callback function
    var onSlide = function(e){
        var columns = $(e.currentTarget).find("td");
        var ranges = [], total = 0, i, s ="Ranges: ", w;
        for(i = 0; i<columns.length; i++){
            w = columns.eq(i).width()-10 - (i==0?1:0);
            ranges.push(w);
            total+=w;
        }        
        for(i=0; i<columns.length; i++){            
            ranges[i] = 100*ranges[i]/total;
            carriage = ranges[i]-w
            s+=" "+ Math.round(ranges[i]) + "%,";           
        }       
        s=s.slice(0,-1);            
        //$("[text]").html(s);
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = s;
    }

    //colResize the table
    $(".range").colResizable({
        liveDrag:true, 
        draggingClass:"rangeDrag", 
        gripInnerHtml:"<div class='rangeGrip'></div>", 
        onResize:onSlide,
        minWidth:8

    });         
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <br/><br/>
    <p>Slider 1</p>
    <div id="slider">        
        <table class="range" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="25%"></td>
                <td width="25%"></td>
                <td width="25%"></td>
                <td width="25%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
        <p id="text">Ranges: 25%, 25%, 25%, 25% </p>        
    </div>


    <br/><br/><br/><br/>

    <p>Slider 2</p>
    <div id="slider">        
        <table class="range" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="25%"></td>
                <td width="25%"></td>
                <td width="25%"></td>
                <td width="25%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p id="text">Ranges: 25%, 25%, 25%, 25% </p>    
    </div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>


main.css

body{
background-color: white;
text-align:center;
}

.center{
text-align:left;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
width:575px;
}

.range{
border:none;
height:37px;
}


#slider:before{
display:block;
background-image: url('../img/rangeBar.png');   
background-position:0px 10px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin-left:9px;
width:560px;
height:30px;
position:relative;
position:absolute;
content:""
}


#range td{
border:none;
}

.rangeGrip{
width:10px;
height:19px;
cursor:e-resize;
background-image: url('../img/slider.png');
z-index:8;
}


.rangeDrag .rangeGrip, .rangeGrip:hover{
background-position:right;
}

#text{
color:#034a92;
float:right;
}
```

Comment: would be nice if you can add this a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/, this will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

There is a multiple solutions for this, depends on mind to mind

I have two solution for your problem

1) If text view part(text box/paragraph) is inside the slider div

a) find the element in to the slider and update it as you updating

```
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = s;
  $(this).find("p").html(s);
```

2) If you want to decouple the slider and view part

a) create view part with some different id

b) on slider div create a dummy attribute may be like data-view="view part id"

c) in event function just get that data-view attr value for the slider and load html on that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [slider](https://github.com/maslick/radiaSlider) I wrote for my personal use a while ago. 
It has both the [linear](https://maslick.neocities.org/slider-linear/) and [circular](https://maslick.neocities.org/slider-circular/) implementations, it is lightweight (~5Kb, written in plain JS) and fully customizable.

[image]
[image]